# How to add a button dynamically from a child form on to the main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a functioning `Button` onto my *main form* when I have selected an item in a `ListView` located on *another form*.

The code below I have placed on the `ListView` form but I am not sure I am doing the right thing as nothing happens when the item is selected.

```
Point newLoc = new Point(5,5);  

Button b = new Button();
b.Size = new Size(10, 50);
b.Location = newLoc;
newLoc.Offset(0, b.Height + 5);
Controls.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to *find* the main form (assuming that you're working with *WinForms*):

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 //TODO: Put the right type instead of MyMainForm
 MyMainForm mainForm = Application
   .OpenForms
   .OfType<MyMainForm>()
   .LastOrDefault();      // If there many opened main forms, let's use the last one
```

Then if the form is found, let's add a button:

```
public partial class MyChildForm : Form {
  // It seems it should be a field to store the next button position
  private Point newLoc = new Point(5, 5);  

  private Button addButtonToMainForm() {
    //TODO: Put the right type instead of MyMainForm
    MyMainForm mainForm = Application
     .OpenForms
     .OfType<MyMainForm>()
     .LastOrDefault();    

    // If Main Form has been found, let's add a button on it
    if (mainForm != null) {
      Button b = new Button() {
        Size     = new Size(10, 50), 
        Location = newLoc,
        Parent   = mainForm, // Place the button on mainForm
      }

      newLoc.Offset(0, b.Height + 5);

      return b;
    }

    return null;
  }

  private void myListView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender,
                                               ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // If item selected (not unselected) 
    if (e.Item.Selected) {
      //TODO: Some other conditions which on the item that has been selected 
      // Button on the Main Form, null if it hasn;t been created
      Button createdButton = addButtonToMainForm();
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am not sure where to place the top piece of code.. could you please advise.. Thanks

Comment: @Ronald: you can find `mainForm` just before adding the button, see my edit.

Comment: Finding the main form is not the problem... the problem is... I am not sure where to place the top code

Comment: @Ronald: Do you mean `Point newLoc = new Point(5, 5);` fragment?

Comment: sorry for the mis understanding … I am referring to    //TODO: Put the right type instead of MyMainForm
 MyMainForm mainForm = Application
   .OpenForms
   .OfType<MyMainForm>()
   .LastOrDefault();

Comment: @Ronald: We search for the main form instance; we do it by main form's type; I *assumed* that the type is `MyMainForm`; however, it may be `Form1` or `MainForm` etc. that's why you have to change `MyMainForm` to *actual* main form's type.

Comment: I have copied your code (line by line ) into the child form, changed the form name from MyMainForm to Form1 as it appears in the Solution Explorer window. Assuming I am doing the right thing... the first error states:-  "Form1 is a variable but is used like a type"  from .OfType<MyMainForm>()

Comment: @Ronald: `Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().LastOrDefault();`

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) is the new message I am getting after code modification..

Comment: @Ronald: you, probably, "missing a using directive": add `using [namespace where your main form implmented];` like `using MyNameSpace;` or you can specify namespace in the code: `MyNameSpace.Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MyNameSpace.Form1>().LastOrDefault();` put correct namespace instead of `MyNameSpace`

Comment: After looking around the Internet.. I discovered a solution which got rid of the errors. In the line Form1 mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().LastOrDefault(); I replaced Form1 with Form.. in both places. It compiled but no Button in sight ! Not sure if that's the right approach.. Definitely wrong result.

Comment: Gotit… the child form was hiding the new button.... Thank you very much for your perseverance     THANK YOU !!